# Extract data from multi level tagged xml

Tags: php, xml

I have a problem with retrieving data from multi tagged xml file.
Here is a example of xml:

```
 <forecast5day>
     <city>Өлгий</city>
     <data>
     <weather>
      <date>2018-10-27</date>
      <temperatureNight>-7</temperatureNight>
      <temperatureDay>7</temperatureDay>
      <phenoIdNight>7</phenoIdNight>
      <phenoNight>Багавтар үүлтэй</phenoNight>
      <phenoIdDay>5</phenoIdDay>
      <phenoDay>Багавтар үүлтэй</phenoDay>
      <windNight>5</windNight>
      <windDay>6</windDay>
     </weather>
    </forecast5day>
```

And my php example

```
<?php
    include 'includes/config.php'; // Initialize db;
    $url = "http://tsag-agaar.gov.mn/forecast_xml";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    // Getting data
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    global $conn; // Creating connection

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

    foreach ($xml -> forecast5day as $row) {
        var_dump($xml-> forest5day);
        $city = $row -> city;
        $date = $row -> date;
        $temperatureNight = $row -> temperatureNight;
        $temperatureDay = $row -> temperatureDay;
        $phenoIdNight = $row -> phenoIdNight;
        $phenoNight = $row -> phenoNight;
        $phenoIdDay = $row -> phenoIdDay;
        $phenoDay = $row -> phenoDay;
        $windNight = $row -> windNight;
        $windDay = $row -> windDay;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO weather(city,wdate,temperatureNight,temperatureDay,phenoIdNight,phenoNight,phenoIdDay,phenoDay,windNight,windDay) VALUES ('{$city}','{$date}','{$temperatureNight}','{$temperatureDay}','{$phenoIdNight}','{$phenoNight}','{$phenoIdDay}','{$phenoDay}','{$windNight}','{$windDay}')";


        $result = $conn -> query($sql);
        if(!$result) {
            echo "MYSQL Error: $sql <br/>";
        } else {
            echo "SUCCES: $sql <br/>";
        }
    }
?>
```

And above snippet gives me:

```
INSERT INTO weather(city,wdate,temperatureNight,temperatureDay,phenoIdNight,phenoNight,phenoIdDay,phenoDay,windNight,windDay) VALUES ('Өлгий','','','','','','','','','')
```

What did i do wrong ? Its something i cannot get a other values except `city`. Any advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, it isn't valid XML. There's no closing `</data>` tag. However that may just be your post and the code is fine. The structure suggests the following will work:

```
$temperatureDay = $row->data->weather->temperatureDay;
```

When there are multiple `weather` elements, `weather` becomes an array.

```
foreach ($row->data->weather as $weather) {
    $temperatureDay = $weather->temperatureDay;
    // and the other values
}
```

Comment: But if i had multiple `weather` tag in one `data` tag ? how to get it ?

Comment: I'd need to see the XML

Comment: is it inside that root loop ?

Comment: I would guess so!

Comment: in my db it just inserting one row.

Comment: inside this `foreach ($xml -> forecast5day as $row) {` but after this `$date = $row -> date;`. And put the insert inside that loop too!

Comment: `foreach ($xml -> forecast5day as $row) {
  $city = $row -> city;
  foreach ($row-> data -> weather as $weather) {
      $date = $row -> data -> weather-> date;
}
}`

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a `</data>` tag from the example XML?

As the information you are trying to read from 'date', 'temperature' etc. is nested within a 'weather' tag, you need to drill down a level into the 'row':

`$row->weather[0]->date`